# My Kotlinplugin for Minecraft is not working

Tags: kotlin, minecraft, minecraft-fabric, minecraft-commands

My Plugin for Fabric 1.19.3 makes an error when i perform a command in chat
Here is the code for the command class

```
package me.lukas.mcplugin1.commands

import net.kyori.adventure.text.Component
import net.kyori.adventure.text.format.TextColor
import org.bukkit.command.Command
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender

class TestCommand : CommandExecutor {

    override fun onCommand(sender: CommandSender, command: Command, label: String, args: Array<out String>?): Boolean {

        sender.sendMessage(Component.text("Test").color(TextColor.color(0 ,200, 0)))

        return false
    }
}
```

And Here is the code for the main class

```
package me.lukas.mcplugin1

import me.lukas.mcplugin1.commands.JumpCommand
import me.lukas.mcplugin1.commands.TestCommand
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin

class McPlugin1 : JavaPlugin() {

    override fun onEnable() {
        // Plugin startup logic
        logger.info("Du hast es geschafft !")
        registerCommands()
    }

    private fun registerCommands () {
        getCommand("jump")?.setExecutor(JumpCommand())
        getCommand("test")?.setExecutor(TestCommand())
        logger.info("Registered Commands")
    }

    override fun onDisable() {
        // Plugin shutdown logic
        logger.info("Tschüss")
    }
}
```

Can anyone Help Me to find the error

I expected that i get the message "test" but it gave me an error
here is the serverconsole error after i enterd the command

```
[17:54:59 WARN]: Unexpected exception while parsing console command "test"
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'test' in plugin Loginplugin v1.0-SNAPSHOT
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:47) ~[paper-api-1.19.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:155) ~[paper-api-1.19.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_19_R2.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:929) ~[paper-1.19.3.jar:git-Paper-365]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_19_R2.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:892) ~[paper-1.19.3.jar:git-Paper-365]
        at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.handleConsoleInputs(DedicatedServer.java:494) ~[paper-1.19.3.jar:git-Paper-365]
        at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.tickChildren(DedicatedServer.java:441) ~[paper-1.19.3.jar:git-Paper-365]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.tickServer(MinecraftServer.java:1397) ~[paper-1.19.3.jar:git-Paper-365]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1173) ~[paper-1.19.3.jar:git-Paper-365]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:316) ~[paper-1.19.3.jar:git-Paper-365]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
        at me.lukas.mcplugin1.commands.TestCommand.onCommand(TestCommand.kt) ~[Mcplugin1.0.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[paper-api-1.19.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass0(PluginClassLoader.java:177) ~[paper-api-1.19.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:124) ~[paper-api-1.19.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[?:?]
        at me.lukas.mcplugin1.commands.TestCommand.onCommand(TestCommand.kt) ~[Mcplugin1.0.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[paper-api-1.19.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        ... 9 more
```

Comment: What version of Kotlin and Java are you using? Are you using Maven or Gradle? What's contents of the build config?

Comment: (The immediate problem isn't with your code — it's that the Kotlin runtime isn't available. But the reason for that will depend on how you built it, and how you're trying to run it.)